# Why isn't the correct value being chosen?

Tags: python, boolean, flowchart

```
a = input("Enter Number 1: ")
b = input("Enter Number 2: ")
c = input("Enter Number 3: ")
if a > b:
    if (a > c):
        print("The largest number is",a)
    else:
        print("The largest number is",c)
else:
    if (b > c):
        print("The largest number is",b)
    else:
        print("The largest number is",c)
```

when I input 12 24 and 6 respectively it chooses 6 as the largest and I have absolutely no clue as to why? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are comparing strings ant not integers.... `a = int(input(...))` would convert the input to an integer (if that is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Simply change it to

```
a = int(input("Enter Number 1: "))
b = int(input("Enter Number 2: "))
c = int(input("Enter Number 3: "))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All inputs are strigs, which are compared alphabetically, so:

```
a = int(input("Enter Number 1: "))
```

In 12 and 24 the first digit comes before than the first digit of 6, so the string '6' is considered bigger.

Full explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20lexicographic%20or,of%20a%20totally%20ordered%20set.)

Answer (score 0):

`python` makes boolean comparisons of strings by comparing the ASCII values of the individual characters. When you enter a value into your `input()` function the computer records it as a string value, not a number.

The string value `"24"` is composed of two characters, `"2"` and `"4"`. The ASCII values for these characters are `50` and `52`, respectively. The string value `"6"` has an ASCII value of `54`. When `"24"` is compared to `"6"` `python` determines that since '54' is greater than '50', `"6"` > `"24"`.

Easy solution is to just convert your inputs to an `int` or `float` data type, like so:

```py
a = int(input("Enter Number 1: "))
b = int(input("Enter Number 2: "))
c = int(input("Enter Number 3: "))
if a > b:
    if (a > c):
        print("The largest number is",a)
    else:
        print("The largest number is",c)
else:
    if (b > c):
        print("The largest number is",b)
    else:
        print("The largest number is",c)
```

This provides your expected output of `The largest number is 24`

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: just to clarify by putting the int there it tells the program to compare the integer values instead of the ASCII values?

Comment: No it's actually turning the string *into* an integer. You could use `float` the same way to turn the values into numbers with decimals. Of course, this only works if the string value *can* be converted to a numeric value. If someone enters `twenty-four` to the input this program will throw an error, since that value can't be obviously transformed into a number (by a computer, anyway).